# How to Limit and Paginate an Array in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking to paginate an array limit the result by 10 per page.

I applied the `array_splice()` method and it seems to just limit the result without making any pagination.

How can I manage this ?

Answer (score 0):

in Controller
define baseurl of that page in which page you want to pagination,

for E.g. I want to apply pagination in painting page then I'm define that as like below,

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'painting';
```

then count total record from database. like for Eg. I have 100 paintings in database then count it how many paintings have there are... like this

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->painting_model->get_count();
```

then define, per_page & uri_segment...

```
$config['per_page'] = 20;
$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
//echo $this->pagination->create_links();
$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data['painting'] = $this->painting_model->get($config["per_page"], $page);
```

then pass that $data to view as like that as per my case, you apply as per your logic...

```
$data['page_name'] = 'painting';
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

**Note:** if you define $config['per_page'] = 10; then it will display 10 record per page,

This is for Your Reference... for More details about Pagination in Codeigniter... [Visit codeigniter Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html)